# Textbox with textmode = date does not show data after executereader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datepicker

I am using VS 2012 asp.net web project and VB.net as programming language.
I have on my form a `textbox` field that its `textmode` property is set to `Date` (Datepicker).

> when I run the following code I can't retrieve the date saved in the record,

```
Protected Sub Srch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Srch.Click        
Dim ARTSQLCON As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=EMBRYOLOGIST;Initial Catalog=ARTSQL;Integrated Security=True")
        Try
            ARTSQLCON.Open()
            If Not Len(FilenumSrc.Text) = 0 Then
                Dim sqlread = New SqlCommand
                sqlread.CommandText = "SELECT Filenum, DOB FROM TblReg WHERE Filenum = " & FilenumSrc.Text
                sqlread.Connection = ARTSQLCON
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader
                dr = sqlread.ExecuteReader
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    dr.Read()
                    FileNumTxt.Text = dr.Item("Filenum")
                    DobTxt.Text = dr.Item("DOB")
                    dr.Close()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            ARTSQLCON.Close()
        End Try 
end sub
```

Comment: do you get any `errors` and what output you are expecting ?

Comment: Hi nad, No at all, I retrieve all saved data successfully except for this field!

Comment: So i guess the mistake is in `aspx` page ?

Comment: Do you mean in the platform?

Comment: No, I mean to say where you have written `<asp:Textbox>` _html_ part

Comment: This is how the control looks like,  <asp:TextBox ID="DobTxt" Text='<%# Bind("DobTxt", "{0:yyyy-MM-DD}")%>' TextMode="Date" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
                        Width="246px"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: you have written wrong, it should not be `TextMode="Date"`, it should be `type="date"`

Comment: Try this one `<asp:TextBox ID="DobTxt" Text='<%# Bind("DobTxt", "{0:yyyy-MM-DD}")%>' type="date" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" Width="246px"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Hi Nad, Unfortunately I am still having the same issue! did not work out

Comment: The date is saved in my SQL server table as yyyy-MM-DD, I mean the same format!

Comment: so is it working or not ?

Comment: No,Unfortunately Not yet

Comment: When I remove this declaration "Text='<%# Bind("DobTxt", "{0:yyyy-MM-DD}")%>' type="date", I can retrieve the saved field again!

Comment: so if there is not issue in removing this, try that way

Comment: But still, I want the user to pick the date rather than entering it!  This is how I minimize entry errors! That declaration removes the date picker property!

Comment: you can add the `datepicker` by javascript. Have a look [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: I see your point, Why Microsoft guys don't provide a method or a solution for things they develop!, I appreciate your time and effort, Thanks

Comment: yes, there are some limitations and they might be working on this, but for now. If you want to implement that, I can help you on this as how to implement the `datepicker`

Comment: Actually I implemented the AJAX date picker extender successfully and it works fine, but the ASP one looks more Cool!

Comment: okay, so you decide and work on it as per your requirement.

Comment: Again, I really Appreciate your input, Thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome Ahmad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim dt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr. 
Item("DOB").ToString())
DobTxt.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt)
```

[ref.: data binding](http://mandrillapp.com/track/click/30209653/forums.asp.net?p=eyJzIjoiR2o4SWVJNlZfdVRUQ3pLWjhaRnBfNzFiRnh3IiwidiI6MSwicCI6IntcInVcIjozMDIwOTY1MyxcInZcIjoxLFwidXJsXCI6XCJodHRwczpcXFwvXFxcL2ZvcnVtcy5hc3AubmV0XFxcL3BcXFwvMjA1NzEzN1xcXC81OTMzNzUyLmFzcHg_UmUrVGV4dGJveCt3aXRoK3RleHRtb2RlK2RhdGUrZG9lcytub3Qrc2hvdytkYXRhK2FmdGVyK2V4ZWN1dGVyZWFkZXJcIixcImlkXCI6XCI2MmZmN2RhOWM2Y2E0ZjI2OTc5YjQ4OTFhNTZlMjU4ZFwiLFwidXJsX2lkc1wiOltcIjRmMDhjZTg4NzJkOTZiNjA1NzhmZDkzN2Y0MjdlYjQ0NzA1ZWE5ZTFcIl19In0)